# Same CSS, same HTML but fonts looks different

Tags: html, css, fonts

Im dump in this, I dont know whats happening here, I made some changes in Elementor (on 1st PC) and after some time I noticed that font looks different a bit, tried go back with changes but no result.. I working also on 2nd PC, where my browser remembered the 'old' version, so I could compare them... and CSS looks the same... HTML are exactly the same... but fonts looks different in some places, more differences are on font weight 700.
Any ideas what makes difference?

screens below, I covered up some things which are different after my changes

[f v1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y67pE.png)

[f v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAHxE.png)

[h v1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T63LQ.png)

[h v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFzef.png)

below CSS of p element in footer (red arrow)
I checked also some other elements, but is the same

v1

```
.footer-widgets .widget_text p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
p {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
.footer-widgets .widget_text {
    line-height: 1.7;
}
.footer-widgets {
    --rz-footer-widget-bottom-spacing: 67px;
}
.footer-widgets {
    --rz-footer-widget-top-spacing: 78px;
}
.footer-widgets {
    color: var(--rz-text-color-gray);
    --rz-footer-widget-border-color: #2b2b2b;
    --rz-footer-widget-top-spacing: 64px;
    --rz-footer-widget-bottom-spacing: 64px;
}
.site-footer {
    --rz-text-color-gray: #cdcdcd;
    --rz-text-color-hover: #fff;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: var(--rz-color-darker);
    color: var(--rz-text-color-gray);
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}
@media (min-width: 991px)
.razzi-catalog-page {
    --razzi-catalog-sidebar-space: 45px;
    --razzi-catalog-sidebar-width: 300px;
}
.elementor-kit-889 {
    --e-global-color-primary: #6EC1E4;
    --e-global-color-secondary: #54595F;
    --e-global-color-text: #7A7A7A;
    --e-global-color-accent: #61CE70;
    --e-global-typography-primary-font-family: "Roboto";
    --e-global-typography-primary-font-weight: 600;
    --e-global-typography-secondary-font-family: "Roboto Slab";
    --e-global-typography-secondary-font-weight: 400;
    --e-global-typography-text-font-family: "Roboto";
    --e-global-typography-text-font-weight: 400;
    --e-global-typography-accent-font-family: "Roboto";
    --e-global-typography-accent-font-weight: 500;
}
body {
    --rz-font-family-primary: Open Sans;
    font-weight: 500;
}
body {
    --rz-color-primary: #03ddfb;
    --rz-color-hover-primary: #03ddfb;
    --rz-background-color-primary: #03ddfb;
    --rz-border-color-primary: #03ddfb;
}
body, button, input, select, optgroup, textarea {
    color: var(--rz-text-color);
    font-family: var(--rz-font-family-primary);
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    --wp--preset--color--black: #000000;
    --wp--preset--color--cyan-bluish-gray: #abb8c3;
    --wp--preset--color--white: #ffffff;
    --wp--preset--color--pale-pink: #f78da7;
    --wp--preset--color--vivid-red: #cf2e2e;
    --wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-orange: #ff6900;
    --wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-amber: #fcb900;
    --wp--preset--color--light-green-cyan: #7bdcb5;
    --wp--preset--color--vivid-green-cyan: #00d084;
    --wp--preset--color--pale-cyan-blue: #8ed1fc;
    --wp--preset--color--vivid-cyan-blue: #0693e3;
    --wp--preset--color--vivid-purple: #9b51e0;
    --wp--preset--gradient--vivid-cyan-blue-to-vivid-purple: linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(6,147,227,1) 0%,rgb(155,81,224) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--light-green-cyan-to-vivid-green-cyan: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(122,220,180) 0%,rgb(0,208,130) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--luminous-vivid-amber-to-luminous-vivid-orange: linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(252,185,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,105,0,1) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--luminous-vivid-orange-to-vivid-red: linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(255,105,0,1) 0%,rgb(207,46,46) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--very-light-gray-to-cyan-bluish-gray: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(238,238,238) 0%,rgb(169,184,195) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--cool-to-warm-spectrum: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(74,234,220) 0%,rgb(151,120,209) 20%,rgb(207,42,186) 40%,rgb(238,44,130) 60%,rgb(251,105,98) 80%,rgb(254,248,76) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--blush-light-purple: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(255,206,236) 0%,rgb(152,150,240) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--blush-bordeaux: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(254,205,165) 0%,rgb(254,45,45) 50%,rgb(107,0,62) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--luminous-dusk: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(255,203,112) 0%,rgb(199,81,192) 50%,rgb(65,88,208) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--pale-ocean: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(255,245,203) 0%,rgb(182,227,212) 50%,rgb(51,167,181) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--electric-grass: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(202,248,128) 0%,rgb(113,206,126) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--midnight: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(2,3,129) 0%,rgb(40,116,252) 100%);
    --wp--preset--duotone--dark-grayscale: url(#wp-duotone-dark-grayscale);
    --wp--preset--duotone--grayscale: url(#wp-duotone-grayscale);
    --wp--preset--duotone--purple-yellow: url(#wp-duotone-purple-yellow);
    --wp--preset--duotone--blue-red: url(#wp-duotone-blue-red);
    --wp--preset--duotone--midnight: url(#wp-duotone-midnight);
    --wp--preset--duotone--magenta-yellow: url(#wp-duotone-magenta-yellow);
    --wp--preset--duotone--purple-green: url(#wp-duotone-purple-green);
    --wp--preset--duotone--blue-orange: url(#wp-duotone-blue-orange);
    --wp--preset--font-size--small: 13px;
    --wp--preset--font-size--medium: 20px;
    --wp--preset--font-size--large: 36px;
    --wp--preset--font-size--x-large: 42px;
}
:root {
    --rz-color-primary: #FF6F61;
    --rz-color-lighter: #ffffff;
    --rz-color-dark: #111111;
    --rz-color-darker: #1f1f1f;
    --rz-color-placeholder: #A0A0A0;
    --rz-color-hover-primary: #FF6F61;
    --rz-background-color-primary: #FF6F61;
    --rz-background-color-light: #ffffff;
    --rz-background-color-gray: #f5f5f5;
    --rz-background-color-dark: #1F1F1F;
    --rz-background-text-color-primary: #ffffff;
    --rz-border-color: #cccccc;
    --rz-border-color-primary: #FF6F61;
    --rz-border-color-light: #e2e2e2;
    --rz-border-color-lighter: #ffffff;
    --rz-border-color-gray: #cdcdcd;
    --rz-border-color-dark: #1f1f1f;
    --rz-text-color-gray: #767676;
    --rz-text-color: #525252;
    --rz-font-family-primary: 'Jost', Arial, sans-serif;
    --rz-font-family-code: Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
    --rz-font-family-pre: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
}
:root {
    --page-title-display: block;
}
:root {
    --woocommerce: #a46497;
    --wc-green: #7ad03a;
    --wc-red: #a00;
    --wc-orange: #ffba00;
    --wc-blue: #2ea2cc;
    --wc-primary: #a46497;
    --wc-primary-text: white;
    --wc-secondary: #ebe9eb;
    --wc-secondary-text: #515151;
    --wc-highlight: #77a464;
    --wc-highligh-text: white;
    --wc-content-bg: #fff;
    --wc-subtext: #767676;
}
:root {
    --wp--preset--font-size--normal: 16px;
    --wp--preset--font-size--huge: 42px;
}
html {
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
html {
    --wp-admin--admin-bar--height: 32px;
    scroll-padding-top: var(--wp-admin--admin-bar--height);
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

v2

```
.footer-widgets .widget_text p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
p {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
.footer-widgets .widget_text {
    line-height: 1.7;
}
.footer-widgets {
    --rz-footer-widget-bottom-spacing: 67px;
}
.footer-widgets {
    --rz-footer-widget-top-spacing: 78px;
}
.footer-widgets {
    color: var(--rz-text-color-gray);
    --rz-footer-widget-border-color: #2b2b2b;
    --rz-footer-widget-top-spacing: 64px;
    --rz-footer-widget-bottom-spacing: 64px;
}
.site-footer {
    --rz-text-color-gray: #cdcdcd;
    --rz-text-color-hover: #fff;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: var(--rz-color-darker);
    color: var(--rz-text-color-gray);
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}
@media (min-width: 991px)
.razzi-catalog-page {
    --razzi-catalog-sidebar-space: 45px;
    --razzi-catalog-sidebar-width: 300px;
}
.elementor-kit-889 {
    --e-global-color-primary: #6EC1E4;
    --e-global-color-secondary: #54595F;
    --e-global-color-text: #7A7A7A;
    --e-global-color-accent: #03DDFB;
    --e-global-typography-primary-font-family: "Roboto";
    --e-global-typography-primary-font-weight: 600;
    --e-global-typography-secondary-font-family: "Roboto Slab";
    --e-global-typography-secondary-font-weight: 400;
    --e-global-typography-text-font-family: "Roboto";
    --e-global-typography-text-font-weight: 400;
    --e-global-typography-accent-font-family: "Roboto";
    --e-global-typography-accent-font-weight: 500;
}
body {
    --rz-font-family-primary: Open Sans;
    font-weight: 500;
}
body {
    --rz-color-primary: #03ddfb;
    --rz-color-hover-primary: #03ddfb;
    --rz-background-color-primary: #03ddfb;
    --rz-border-color-primary: #03ddfb;
}
body, button, input, select, optgroup, textarea {
    color: var(--rz-text-color);
    font-family: var(--rz-font-family-primary);
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    --wp--preset--color--black: #000000;
    --wp--preset--color--cyan-bluish-gray: #abb8c3;
    --wp--preset--color--white: #ffffff;
    --wp--preset--color--pale-pink: #f78da7;
    --wp--preset--color--vivid-red: #cf2e2e;
    --wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-orange: #ff6900;
    --wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-amber: #fcb900;
    --wp--preset--color--light-green-cyan: #7bdcb5;
    --wp--preset--color--vivid-green-cyan: #00d084;
    --wp--preset--color--pale-cyan-blue: #8ed1fc;
    --wp--preset--color--vivid-cyan-blue: #0693e3;
    --wp--preset--color--vivid-purple: #9b51e0;
    --wp--preset--gradient--vivid-cyan-blue-to-vivid-purple: linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(6,147,227,1) 0%,rgb(155,81,224) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--light-green-cyan-to-vivid-green-cyan: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(122,220,180) 0%,rgb(0,208,130) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--luminous-vivid-amber-to-luminous-vivid-orange: linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(252,185,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,105,0,1) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--luminous-vivid-orange-to-vivid-red: linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(255,105,0,1) 0%,rgb(207,46,46) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--very-light-gray-to-cyan-bluish-gray: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(238,238,238) 0%,rgb(169,184,195) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--cool-to-warm-spectrum: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(74,234,220) 0%,rgb(151,120,209) 20%,rgb(207,42,186) 40%,rgb(238,44,130) 60%,rgb(251,105,98) 80%,rgb(254,248,76) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--blush-light-purple: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(255,206,236) 0%,rgb(152,150,240) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--blush-bordeaux: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(254,205,165) 0%,rgb(254,45,45) 50%,rgb(107,0,62) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--luminous-dusk: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(255,203,112) 0%,rgb(199,81,192) 50%,rgb(65,88,208) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--pale-ocean: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(255,245,203) 0%,rgb(182,227,212) 50%,rgb(51,167,181) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--electric-grass: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(202,248,128) 0%,rgb(113,206,126) 100%);
    --wp--preset--gradient--midnight: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(2,3,129) 0%,rgb(40,116,252) 100%);
    --wp--preset--duotone--dark-grayscale: url(#wp-duotone-dark-grayscale);
    --wp--preset--duotone--grayscale: url(#wp-duotone-grayscale);
    --wp--preset--duotone--purple-yellow: url(#wp-duotone-purple-yellow);
    --wp--preset--duotone--blue-red: url(#wp-duotone-blue-red);
    --wp--preset--duotone--midnight: url(#wp-duotone-midnight);
    --wp--preset--duotone--magenta-yellow: url(#wp-duotone-magenta-yellow);
    --wp--preset--duotone--purple-green: url(#wp-duotone-purple-green);
    --wp--preset--duotone--blue-orange: url(#wp-duotone-blue-orange);
    --wp--preset--font-size--small: 13px;
    --wp--preset--font-size--medium: 20px;
    --wp--preset--font-size--large: 36px;
    --wp--preset--font-size--x-large: 42px;
}
:root {
    --rz-color-primary: #FF6F61;
    --rz-color-lighter: #ffffff;
    --rz-color-dark: #111111;
    --rz-color-darker: #1f1f1f;
    --rz-color-placeholder: #A0A0A0;
    --rz-color-hover-primary: #FF6F61;
    --rz-background-color-primary: #FF6F61;
    --rz-background-color-light: #ffffff;
    --rz-background-color-gray: #f5f5f5;
    --rz-background-color-dark: #1F1F1F;
    --rz-background-text-color-primary: #ffffff;
    --rz-border-color: #cccccc;
    --rz-border-color-primary: #FF6F61;
    --rz-border-color-light: #e2e2e2;
    --rz-border-color-lighter: #ffffff;
    --rz-border-color-gray: #cdcdcd;
    --rz-border-color-dark: #1f1f1f;
    --rz-text-color-gray: #767676;
    --rz-text-color: #525252;
    --rz-font-family-primary: 'Jost', Arial, sans-serif;
    --rz-font-family-code: Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
    --rz-font-family-pre: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
}
:root {
    --page-title-display: block;
}
:root {
    --woocommerce: #a46497;
    --wc-green: #7ad03a;
    --wc-red: #a00;
    --wc-orange: #ffba00;
    --wc-blue: #2ea2cc;
    --wc-primary: #a46497;
    --wc-primary-text: white;
    --wc-secondary: #ebe9eb;
    --wc-secondary-text: #515151;
    --wc-highlight: #77a464;
    --wc-highligh-text: white;
    --wc-content-bg: #fff;
    --wc-subtext: #767676;
}
:root {
    --wp--preset--font-size--normal: 16px;
    --wp--preset--font-size--huge: 42px;
}
html {
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
html {
    --wp-admin--admin-bar--height: 32px;
    scroll-padding-top: var(--wp-admin--admin-bar--height);
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: without [mcve] it will be hard to provide any feedback

Comment: @depperm
I just edited with examples, i had problem with "code error" and i didnt know why lol, solution - added images links should be in new lines / paragraphs

Comment: Without seeing how you are loading that font I don’t think any answer will be more than a guess. If you aren’t loading it then maybe your two PCs are defaulting to different fonts.

Comment: @A Haworth I added how I loading the fonts, from the beggining it was 'Open Sans' and 'Open Sans Condensed'

Answer (score 0):

@A Haworth

I loading fonts in the same way before and after the "change"... see below.

I worked on this website about a week, and fonts were in the same look, it changed after some event, and i don't know why and when exactly...

```
<style id="kirki-inline-styles">
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjZ0B4taVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjZ0B4kaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjZ0B4saVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjZ0B4jaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* hebrew */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjZ0B4iaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0590-05FF, U+200C-2010, U+20AA, U+25CC, U+FB1D-FB4F;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjZ0B4vaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjZ0B4uaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjZ0B4gaVQUwaEQXjM.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjr0B4taVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjr0B4kaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjr0B4saVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjr0B4jaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* hebrew */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjr0B4iaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0590-05FF, U+200C-2010, U+20AA, U+25CC, U+FB1D-FB4F;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjr0B4vaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjr0B4uaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjr0B4gaVQUwaEQXjM.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsgH1x4taVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsgH1x4kaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsgH1x4saVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsgH1x4jaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* hebrew */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsgH1x4iaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0590-05FF, U+200C-2010, U+20AA, U+25CC, U+FB1D-FB4F;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsgH1x4vaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsgH1x4uaVQUwaEQXjN_mQ.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsgH1x4gaVQUwaEQXjM.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans-condensed/z7NFdQDnbTkabZAIOl9il_O6KJj73e7Ff0GmDujMQbeS2AopSg.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans-condensed/z7NFdQDnbTkabZAIOl9il_O6KJj73e7Ff0GmDuHMQbeS2AopSg.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans-condensed/z7NFdQDnbTkabZAIOl9il_O6KJj73e7Ff0GmDunMQbeS2AopSg.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans-condensed/z7NFdQDnbTkabZAIOl9il_O6KJj73e7Ff0GmDubMQbeS2AopSg.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans-condensed/z7NFdQDnbTkabZAIOl9il_O6KJj73e7Ff0GmDurMQbeS2AopSg.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans-condensed/z7NFdQDnbTkabZAIOl9il_O6KJj73e7Ff0GmDuvMQbeS2AopSg.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://MYWEBSITE/wp-content/fonts/open-sans-condensed/z7NFdQDnbTkabZAIOl9il_O6KJj73e7Ff0GmDuXMQbeS2Ao.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
</style>
```